# SQL: Matching tables using mathematical operation

Tags: sql, sas

I have a table with a set of 300'000 units, where the location of each unit is defined by a coordinate `(X,Y)`. I would like to know which units are within a certain distance to each and every one?

Ex.

```
UnitiID   X   Y
A         10  15
B         10  25
C         25  15


proc sql;
    create table work.Test2 as
    select distinct
    a.UnitID,
    a.X,
    a.Y,
    b.UnitID as CloseUnit label="CloseUnit",
    sqrt( (a.X-b.X)**2 + (a.Y-b.Y)**2 ) as distance
    from
    work.Test as a
    left join
    work.Test as b
    on
    0<sqrt( (a.X-b.X)**2 + (a.Y-b.Y)**2 ) <=15
    ;
quit;
```

Result:

```
UnitiID   X   Y   CloseUnit  Distance
A         10  15  B          10
A         10  15  C          15
B         10  25  A          10
C         25  15  A          15
```

This requires a lot of cpu time for the entire table, since we would do 300'000^2 comparisons, how could I preform this task?

Comment: Several DBMS have spatial features. Which are you working on? (SQL-Server, Postgres, Oracle, ...?)

Comment: You could add an extra where restiction on the bounding box ((x +- r), (y+- d)) That will shave off a lot of the comparisons. Could be `ABS(a.x-b.x) <= r AND ABS(a.y-b.y) <=r` @ypercube: SAS has a (limited) implementation of the SQL language.

Comment: You could skip sqrt by squaring both sides (i.e. removing sqrt and using 225 in place of 15).

Comment: SAS has a GEODIST function that calculates the distance between 2 sets of coordinates.  It may not improve performance, but it saves typing out the formula and you can specify what distance measurement to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several optimizations come to mind.  First, you could check for distance along the X and Y axis.  If either is larger than 15, the points cannot be in range.  A subquery would instruct the database to do the faster check first:

```
select  *
from    (
        select  a.X as aX
        ,       b.X as bX
        ,       a.Y as aY
        ,       b.Y as bY
        from    Test a
        join    Test b
        on      abs(a.X - b.X) <= 15
                and abs(a.Y - b.Y) <= 15
        ) as SubQueryAlias
where   sqrt( (aX-bX)**2 + (aY-bY)**2 ) <= 15
```

A second optimization would be to move the `sqrt` calculation to the right:

```
where   (aX-bX)**2 + (aY-bY)**2 <= 15**2
```

Squaring is faster than rooting, especially when done on a constant.

For even further optimization, check out the [Wikipedia article on Geohashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash).

Comment: i need to calculate distance by (aX-bX)**2 + (aY-bY)**2 this formula and show distance acording to  ax bx ay by point how to make query